# iOS: CGContextRef drawRect does not agree with input

Tags: iphone, ios, drawrect, setneedsdisplay, cgcontextref

**Background** : I would like to draw blocks when the user touch up somewhere. If the block is there, I want to erase it. I manage the blocks by using `NSMutableArray`to keep track of points where the block should go. Every time user touches, it will determine if the touch place already contained a block or not and manage the array accordingly.

**Problem** : I got a very weird feedback from this. First of all, everything in the array works as I wanted. The problem comes when the user wanted to erase a block. While the array is maintained correctly, the drawing seems to ignore the change in the array. It will not remove anything but the last dot. And even that flashes toggles on and off when the user clicked elsewhere.

**Here is the code** :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"drawrect current array %@",pointArray);
    for (NSValue *pointValue in pointArray){
        CGPoint point = [pointValue CGPointValue];
        [self drawSquareAt:point];
    }
} 

- (void) drawSquareAt:(CGPoint) point{
    float x = point.x * scale;
    float y = point.y * scale; 

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x+scale, y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x+scale, y+scale);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y+scale);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [aTouch locationInView:self];
    point = CGPointMake( (int) (point.x/scale), (int) (point.y/scale));
    NSLog(@"Touched at %@", [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]]);

    NSValue *pointValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
    int i = [pointArray indexOfObject:pointValue];
    NSLog(@"Index at %i",i);
    if (i < [pointArray count]){
        [pointArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"remove");
    }else {
        [pointArray addObject:pointValue];
        NSLog(@"add");
    }
    NSLog(@"Current array : %@", pointArray);

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

`scale` is defined as 16.
`pointArray` is a member variable of the view.

**To Test** : You can drop this into any UIView and add that to the viewController to see the effect.

**Question** : How do I get the drawing to agree with the array?

---

**Update + Explanation**: I am aware of the cost of this approach but it is only created for me to get a quick figure. It will not be used in the real application, thus, please do not get hung up about how expensive it is. I only created this capability to get a value in `NSString` (`@"1,3,5,1,2,6,2,5,5,..."`) of a figure I draw. This will become more efficient when I am actually using it with no redrawing. please stick to the question asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you are actually clearing what you drew previously.  Unless you explicitly clear (such as by filling with `UIRectFill()` - which, as an aside, is a more convenient way to draw rectangles than filling an explicit path), Quartz is going to just draw over your old content, which will cause unexpected behavior on attempts at erasure.

So... what happens if you put at the beginning of `-drawRect:`:

```
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill]; // Or whatever your background color is
UIRectFill([self bounds]);
```

(This is of course horrendously inefficient, but per your comment, I am disregarding that fact.)

(As a separate aside, you probably should wrap your drawing code in a `CGContextSaveGState()`/`CGContextRestoreGState()` pair to avoid tainting the graphics context of any calling code.)

EDIT: I always forget about this property since I usually want to draw more complex backgrounds anyway, but you can likely achieve similar results by setting `clearsContextBeforeDrawing:YES` on the UIView.

Comment: Your `setFill` works perfectly. But `clearsContextBeforeDrawing:YES` did not work. It is very inefficient but for my purpose, it is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems a little weird to me because every time the touchesEnded method is called you need to redraw (which is an expensive operation) and also need keep track of the squares. I suggest you subclass an UIView and implement the drawRect: method, so the view knows how to draw itself and implement the touchesEnded method in your view controller, where you can check  if you have touched a squareView then remove it from view controller's view otherwise create a squareView and add it as subview to the view controller's view.

Comment: Thank you for looking out for me. If you know the answer to my actual question, please contribute. Please look at my update reply above.